# Cleaning, sanitizing

Tags: cleaning

I have been cleaning all of my equipment with vinegar and this has always worked well. However recently i have had several brews that have been flat after the relevant brewing period and I have changed nothing about the process. I have always used the Coopers home brew kits and their canned brews without problems.  All bottles are completely sealed with no leaks and all have been primed with Coopers carbonated drops as per their instructions. Could using the vinegar as a cleaner be the causing the problem with flat brews?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason that a small amount of vinegar in a bottle would affect carbonation.

Answer (score -2):

If there is any vinegar still in the bottles during bottling, you could potentially kill the yeast for conditioning.  Your rinse or drying may have not been effective for this batch.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you may not have got all the vinegar out of the bottles. That would kill the yeast, which is what carbonates the bottles by consuming the priming sugar.

You might consider using something other than vinegar as well. I typically use an iodine based sanitizer, such as IO Star.

Comment: He is using the vinegar to clean, not \sanitize, according to the post.

Comment: Plus some sour beer has acetic acid in it and does just fine.